# BackgroundWorker not working

Tags: .net, vba, backgroundworker

Hi I need help with backgroundworker on my program using vb net, everytime I add the backgroundworker the program doesn't respond using the button 4, what did I do wrong?

Please find below code I used:

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker2.DoWork

    For I = 0 To 200 'Telling the program to count from 0 - 200
        runMacro()

        BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(I)
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
    ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
End Sub
```

And find below code for my runMacro():

```
Private Sub runMacro()
    '~~> Define your Excel Objects
    Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook

    '~~> Start Excel and open the workbook.
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("\Projects\MV_tool\MV_tool\audit\macroaudit.xlsm")
    ' xlApp.Visible = False
    '~~> Run the macros.
    xlApp.Run("Module1.Txt_Excel_tool")
    'Source1.Close(SaveChanges:=False)
    'For i = 0 To 100
    'BackgroundWorker2.ReportProgress(i)
    ' Next
    'xlApp.Run("Module2.Txt_Excel_tool")
    '~~> Clean-up: Close the workbook and quit Excel.
    xlApp.Visible = True
    xlWorkBook.Close(False)
    'Source1.Close(SaveChanges:=False)
    '~~> Quit the Excel Application
    ' xlApp.Quit()


End Sub
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint in `Button4_Click()`. Does it ever get hit?

Comment: Thank you so much, I already solved this problem.